# Bedeutungen von "hinkriegen"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, vocabulary

Als ich das Wort "hinkriegen" in mein Wörterbuch eintragen wollte, bin ich auf die Tatsache gestoßen, dass es extrem viele Bedeutungen hat, die zwar ein ähnliches Wesen haben (wahrscheinlich), aber eigentlich sehr unterschiedlich sind. Hier sind 5 von denen, die ich bemerkt habe:

1. (erfolgreich) fertigbringen, bewältigen: Das Projekt ist fertig, das haben wir gut hingekriegt.
2. reparieren: Kannst du mein Fahrrad wieder hinkriegen?
3. organisieren: Ich muss noch ein paar Dinge für die Party hinkriegen.
4. (eine Lösung) finden: Wir müssen eine gute Antwort darauf hinkriegen.
5. überzeugt werden: Man muss es hinkriegen, dass es keine Gefahr da gibt.

Duden gibt die ersten zwei Bedeutungen an, bei DWDS gibt es nur die erste. Wohl können die anderen verallgemeinert werden, damit sie den ersten entsprechen? Ansonsten verstehe ich nicht, warum sie in den Wörterbüchern nicht vorhanden sind.

Answer (score 4):

Die generelle Bedeutung, die diesen möglichen Verwendungen gemeinsam ist: Ein Ziel, ein erwünschtes Resultat erreichen, oft unter Überwindung von Schwierigkeiten.

Answer (score 3):

"Etwas hinkriegen" wird meistens als "etwas fertigbringen / bewältigen / schaffen" verstanden. Außerdem kann es auch im Sinne von "etwas in Ordnung bringen" verwendet werden. Die Interpretation "reparieren" ist insofern korrekt, aber zu eng gefasst. Wie verhält es sich mit den Sätzen  3. bis 5. ?

> Ich muss noch ein paar Dinge für die Party hinkriegen

klingt holprig. Man würde es auch nicht im Sinne von "organisieren" verstehen, sondern im Sinne von "erledigen" - und das ist sehr nahe an "fertigbringen".

> Wir müssen eine gute Antwort darauf hinkriegen

klingt auch etwas unbeholfen. In diesem Satz bedeutet es "finden" oder "erarbeiten" - und eines dieser Worte sollte man auch verwenden.

> Man muss es hinkriegen, dass es keine Gefahr da gibt

ist völlig in Ordnung, aber man würde es nicht im Sinne von "überzeugt werden" verstehen, sondern im Sinne von "fertigbringen" oder "schaffen".

Comment: Eigentlich stammen der vierte und der fünfte Sätze aus Artikeln von "Die Zeit": ich habe sie im DWDS-Korpus gefunden und ein bisschen vereinfacht oder umformuliert. Hier sind ihre originalen Versionen:
"Und da liegt eben die Herausforderung, vor der die Europäer stehen: Angesichts des Zerfalls und der Krisen unmittelbar vor der eigenen Haustür müssen wir eine wirklich europäische Antwort hinkriegen".
"Man muss es hinkriegen, dass das, was passiert, nur das bestätigt, was man immer schon gesagt hat".

Comment: @aldin Trittins Wortwahl in "müssen wir eine wirklich europäische Antwort hinkriegen" finde ich unglücklich. Vielleicht ist das im "Politsprech" so üblich, aber besser wäre "müssen wir es hinkriegen, eine  wirklich europäische Antwort zu geben (oder zu finden)."